# Как получить лексикографически первую строку из списка? (Linq)

Tags: c#, строки, linq

Есть словарь с частотой встречаемости строк в тексте, надо получить строку с максимальной частотой. Если есть несколько строк с одинаковой частотой, то использовать лексикографически первую (использую string.CompareOrdinal).

Следующий способ не подойдет, т.к. не используется `string.CompareOrdinal()`.

```
var res = maxRatingBigrams.Min(s => s.Key);
```

Хочу получить что-то в духе:

```
var res = maxRatingBigrams.Min((x, y) => string.CompareOrdinal(x.Key, y.Key));
```

Как сделать это грамотнее?

Comment: Подозреваю тебе нужно использовать [Класс SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: maxRatingBigrams.Sort((x, y) => string.CompareOrdinal(x.Key, y.Key));var res = maxRatingBigrams.First().Key;

Пока сделал такую заглушку, но сортировка дороже нахождения минимума

Comment: В SortedDictionary не надо делать сортировку, он уже отсортирован, надо просто взять первый элемент

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Только но в нем можно использовать только System.StringComparer ?

Comment: _Только но в нем можно использовать только System.StringComparer ?_  - не понял вопрос. Несколько его конструкторов принимают IEqualityCompaper поэтому ты можешь передать туда любой Comparer

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, сам не подумал бы использовать другую структуру.

Comment: @BanyRule, вам нужен метод `MinBy` из пакета morelinq, сам пакет можно подключить из NuGet или просто взять исходник этого одного метода на GitHub и добавить к себе в код

Comment: `SortedDictionary`, конечно, удобен, но он сортирует при каждой вставке, т. е. может оказаться неэффективен в некоторых сценариях.

Answer (score 3):

Как Вам посоветовал @Grundy, попробуйте использовать [Класс SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx).

Пример:

```
SortedDictionary<string, int> dict = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();

dict.Add("aaa", 5);
dict.Add("bbb", 7);
dict.Add("ccc", 8);
dict.Add("ddd", 8);
dict.Add("eee", 4);
dict.Add("fff", 4);

int max = dict.Values.Max();
string keyMax = "";
foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
{
    if (dict[key] == max)
        keyMax = key;
}

Console.WriteLine(keyMax.ToString() + dict[keyMax]);
```

Answer (score 2):

вот я расширил 'LINQ' (вариант extension method).но алгоритм от оригинального источника (reverse сделал). **не путайте имя просто так написал 'OrdinalyMin'**.

[Orginal Enumerable LINQ Min Method .NET](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3)

```
  public static class Extension
  {
     public static TSource OrdinalyMin<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> 
             source,Func<TSource,TSource,int> func)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Source Empty!");
        if (func == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Func Predicate Null!");

        TSource value = default(TSource);
        // Reference Type..
        if (value == null)
        {
            foreach (TSource x in source)
            {
                if (x != null && (value == null || func(x, value) < 0))
                    value = x;
            }
            return value;
        }
        // Value Type..
        else
        {
            bool hasValue = false;
            foreach (TSource x in source)
            {
                if (hasValue)
                {
                    if (func(x, value) < 0)
                        value = x;
                }
                else
                {
                    value = x;
                    hasValue = true;
                }
            }
            if (hasValue)
                return value;
            throw new Exception("Elements Empty!");
        }
    }
}
```

пример.

```
  Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dic.Add(3, "oKK");
        dic.Add(1, "Bek");
        dic.Add(4, "Aek");
        dic.Add(2, "Aek");
        dic.Add(6, "Aek");

  KeyValuePair<int,string> minResult = dic.OrdinalyMin((x, y) => 
                                string.CompareOrdinal(x.Value, y.Value));
  Console.WriteLine("Key {0} Value {1}", minResult.Key, 
                                         minResult.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
maxRatingBigrams.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value)
                .ThenBy(kvp => kvp.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal)
                .First()
```